# move_uploaded_file() dont do the job

Tags: php

This is my code and the move_uploaded_file is not working 
i did echo on my files and file target and temp, they are correct
i put the file to move on my pc and didn t and nothing.
every echo is the error echo and i saw the permissions of the folder locations.

```
$target = "files/"; 
$fileTarget = $target.$teste;   
$tempFileName = $tempN;

if(move_uploaded_file($tempFileName, $fileTarget)){
    echo "<br>";
    echo "I am there yeeee";
}else{
    echo "<br>";
    echo "erro";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you checked the permissions or do you get permission errors?

Comment: i check the permissions

Comment: Start with `var_dump($_FILES);` to verify first of all whether you actually _have_ a successfully uploaded file.

Comment: have you checked your logs?

Comment: (Wait, _is_ this even a file upload? You are not using $_FILES anywhere, but seem to be specifying your own path to where the file is located. move_uploaded_file only works for actual file uploads, it explicitly has a check for that build in …)

Comment: What are `$teste` and `$tempN`? Also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: $_SESSION['file'] = basename($_FILES['my_file']['name']);
            $_SESSION['tempname'] = $_FILES["my_file"]["tmp_name"];
            var_dump($_FILES);

Comment: var dump array is 0

Comment: On your HTML form have you got `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`?

Comment: Yes i have the <form enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: temp -> C:\xampp\tmp\phpFC56.tmp 
filetarget-> files/Untitled.png 
file->Untitled.png

Comment: i saw the error i change the      if(move_uploaded_file($tempFileName, $fileTarget)){ to move_uploaded_file($_FILES["my_file"]["tmp_name"], $fileTarget); he dont like the variable but now i have to change a few thinks on the code....